# Change UTC time to Local in Entity Framework before making comparison

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a application where Entity Framework Database First Approach is used and I have to compare dates in the query.

I want to change TimestampUTC, which is a database field, to Local time before comparing with startDate and endDate.

Is is possible to change x.TimestamdUTC somehow in the below query?

```cs
  using (var db = new testEntities())
        {
            int numberOfRecords;

            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90).Date;
            DateTime endDate= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;

            numberOfRecords = db.Logs.Where(x => x.TimestampUTC >= startDate && x.TimestampUTC <= endDate).Count();

            Console.WriteLine("Total records = " + numberOfRecords);
        }
```

Comment: Use `DateTime.UtcNow`, so that `startDate` and `endDate` are also UTC for comparison.

Comment: can't you change local date to TimestampUTC?

Comment: you shouldn't change the time `x.TimestampUTC` to local time. You should rather change the `startDate`  and `endDate` to UTC for comparison. Converting the x.TimestampUTC to local time will make the query inefficient and very expensive. The DB Server might not even use the Index on those columns.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work @Simant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` method to return a local time representation of a given DateTime instance. So you're query would like this:

```cs
numberOfRecords = db.Logs.Where(x => x.TimestampUTC.ToLocaTime() >= startDate && x.TimestampUTC <= endDate).Count();
```

This would work, but not very good, as (I think) LINQ can't translate the `ToLocalTime` method to SQL, meaning every entry would be loaded into memory and the converted then filtered and counted. Instead let's go the other way around and use `ToUniversalTime()` on our start and end dates like so:

```cs
var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90).Date.ToUniversalTime();
var endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date.ToUniversalTime();

// Same LINQ as in your question
numberOfRecords = db.Logs.Where(x => x.TimestampUTC >= startDate && x.TimestampUTC <= endDate).Count();
```

**Edit:** Thanks to ckuri's comment I remembered about `DateTime.UtcNow`. So instead of calling `ToUniversalTime()` on the start and end date, you could directly call `DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(...`.

Also, while I'm at it, I personally prefer the `Subtract` Method on the DateTime objects as it makes it a little more clear to see what's going on, so like so:

```cs
var startDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(90));
```